# crystal report images non functional

Tags: crystal-reports, report

currently i have js files in 
**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\CrystalReportWebFormViewer3\js**

and even the aspnet_client folder with **aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\CrystalReportWebFormViewer3\js** in my application folder
but when i am using crystal report the report is visible  & even the images on report viewer is visible but non functional when i click on **print** / **export** or refresh a blank page is displayed.

I have the **aspnet_client** mapped in IIS

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy all Files from below folder to IIS aspnet_client folder

C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin\